# Webscrape Json using Excel VBA using VBA-JSON addon

Tags: javascript, json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I followed the guide on
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON to install the package, in addition to enabling Microsoft Scripting Runtime and Microsoft Script Control.

I was hoping to receive guidance on how to import the following dictionaries into a data table that will read:

| fiscalDateEnding | totalRevenue | netIncome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dates | $ |  |

for all of the dates listed on this page: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=INCOME_STATEMENT&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

Thank you!

Comment: (Powerquery) Use the inbuilt data > tools > From web and use your url. Pretty simple to then expand the json returned via two separate lists expanded into tables (annual v quarterly). You can do this as two separate queries and merge, keep separate, or even take the M scripts from the separate ones and re-write into a single script. Please see [mcve] and [ask] for advice on showing us what you have tried, explaining where you are stuck and supplying a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to use Power Query, but to answer your question about using a vba routine, I provide the following code: *(I put the json into a text file, but you can read it directly from alphaVantage)*

```
Option Explicit
Sub processJson()
    Dim jsonFile As String
    Dim jsonText As String
    Dim jsonObj As Object
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject, TS As TextStream
    Dim vRes As Variant, I As Long, J As Long
        
jsonFile = "c:\users\ron\desktop\json.txt"
Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile(jsonFile, ForReading, False, TristateUseDefault)
jsonText = TS.ReadAll

Set jsonObj = parsejson(jsonText)

Dim annReports As Collection
Set annReports = jsonObj("annualReports")

ReDim vRes(0 To annReports.Count, 1 To 3)

'Headers (also serve as keys to the dictionaries in the collection)
    vRes(0, 1) = "fiscalDateEnding"
    vRes(0, 2) = "totalRevenue"
    vRes(0, 3) = "netIncome"

'populate data
For I = 1 To annReports.Count
    For J = 1 To 3
        vRes(I, J) = annReports(I)(vRes(0, J))
    Next J
Next I

With Worksheets("json")
    .Cells.Clear
    With .Range("a1").Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
        .Value = vRes
        .Style = "Output"
        Range(.Columns(2), .Columns(3)).NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "" - ""_);_(@_)"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End With
    
End Sub
```

For your data, here is the output:

[image]

I suggest you step through the macro, examining the locals window at the various steps in order to best understand what is going on.